# The difference between ''cringy'' and ''cringey''

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, pronunciation

Can anyone explain to me the difference between these two words?
I looked up them in a dictionary but I find the both meanings to be quite similar. 
Also, is there any difference in their pronuncation? Thank you.

Comment: Both are simply ad-hoc adjectivizations of "cringe".  Apparently "cringey" is listed as a "new word suggestion" by Collins, but neither is officially in a standard English dictionary yet.

Comment: @HotLicks: Isn't the online Oxford Dictionary regarded as a standard dictionary? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cringy

Comment: @MarkBannister - When I Googled the Oxford didn't come up.

Comment: They're variant spellings of a cringeworthy word.

Answer (score 6):

By contrast to the Urban Dictionary, the online Oxford Dictionary gives both spellings as variants of each other, with the following [meanings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cringy):

> 1 Servile; cringing; timid.
>
> 2 =cringeworthy.

Answer (score -1):

According to Urban dictionary there is a difference in meaning:

CRINGY: cringy is when something is just so unpleasant that it makes you literally cringe.
CRINGEY: embarrassing or making feel uncomfortable

Comment: I don't agree that these are "different meanings" so much as the same meaning written up by different people.

Comment: Urban dictionary is useful for finding unexpected exceptions to rules, but not for finding the rules themselves.